# Meaning of "fare da sfogo a"

Tags: word-meaning, meaning, translation

I'm reading [this article](https://www.recensionelibro.it/intervista-erri-de-luca)

> Napoli era una città del sud del mondo, piena di infanzia inferocita e decimata dai morbi, dalle mancanze, città a cosce aperte per ***fare da sfogo alle*** migliaia di marinai della sesta flotta degli stati uniti, città che campava di loro e di rimesse di emigranti.

What does "fare da sfogo a" mean in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context it means that Naples becomes a way to let off steam, to relax.

In Naples sailors, after performing the assigned tasks or duties, could find a lot of "girls" to have fun (Naples is defined as "città a cosce aperte", a city that lived on this situation).